# How to generate a PDF from a view using media=print for styles

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, itext, print-css

Most of the questions in stackoverflow or in other forums, show how to generate views and sends them by email.

But my goal is to generate a PDF from a view with the `media=print` format and sends it in attachment by email.

I have a view that displays a report.
I use CSS Print to display this report in a print format. (Basically I display some elements and hide others).

How can I generate a PDF from this view (with format `media=print`) and send it by e-mail in attachment.

I am using ActionMailer to send emails and iTextSharp to generate PDFs

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm too trying to create PDF using our print CSS

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and did a lot of googling. but could not find a proper solution. There was a 3rd party dll called "PDFGenerator" but the output is not neat and nice.
So I chose another solution.
I created a report file(.rdlc) with the UI i want print it as a pdf by the code.
Here is my sample code
[GitHub](https://github.com/dimuthudrw/ReportToPdfConverter)